# How to create unique pendingIntents without requestCode

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

How can I create unique pending intents with same requestCode and then cancel them? I would like to separate them with UUID for example. [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent) says that by adding extra doesn't make them unique maybe I could setData with my generated string UUID?

this is only option I came up with, but not sure if it would work:

```
 val intent = Intent(context, cls)
 val uniqueId = Uri.parse("dedf788c-ecd7-43f4-a691-03e2117fd50e")
 intent.data = uniqueId

 val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
```

Comment: You can pass 0 if you don't want to use it.

Comment: but i need to make it unique as well because I would like to create multiple pending intents with same BroadcastReceiver and request code

Comment: I don't really understand why you would need to use the same request code, but it is possible (see my answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this question maybe a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52428352/android-alarm-manager-with-multiple-pending-intents/52428675#52428675).

Your requestCode must be unique otherwise PendingIntent will be updated to last intent if you use the same requestCode(old Api <22).

If your are not using action, you can add your UUID as de dummy action to make them unique.
You have to store the requestCode to be able to cancel old PendingIntent.

Comment: So if I will create two pending intents let's say both with requestCode 0 and set different dummy actions will it make them unique even on API 21 and lower?

Comment: if you set a dummyAction it will be unique for all android API. To cancel a PendingIntent, you have to store uuid passed on action to be able to cancel it. if you use different requestCode without Action, it will be unique only for Api <22.

Comment: Thank you for the help

Comment: Nonsense! You don't need different `requestCode` if the ACTIONs are different!

Comment: on Android <22 if pending intent with same action and request code different, it will be seen as different intent. From API >22, it's no longer working. Intent.filterEqualt is used to compare pendingIntent(documentation says that the case from API 1 , but it's no true on API <22, request code is also used...  ).  Of course if we add a unique action, all intent will be unique on all android version. The Uri used is not a valid, so that's why its better to use Action then Data but it work also...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need different `requestCode`s. You can use ACTION or DATA to differentiate the `PendingIntent`s. For example, you could set the your GUID as ACTION and this is enough to make the `PendingIntent` unique.

But you can also use different DATA (as you have in your original code). That also works.

NOTE: However, you are trying to parse an invalid URI. You should try something like:

```
val uniqueId = Uri.parse("scheme:///dedf788c-ecd7-43f4-a691-03e2117fd50e")
```

Comment: I have a similar use case where I use an AlarmManager and a PendingIntent to trigger an Intent to send a message to a BroadcastReciever to send a message to a Service to fire a Notification.  But multiple alarms are not firing the Notifications because I think the PendingIntent is being overwritten.  I've made the PendingIntent unique trying unique setActions and setData.  For setData, would I need to put a <data /> element in the Manfiest for the intent-filtering the Uri?

Comment: @AJW Please open a new question. A comment in an existing question is not the right approach.